# My github page won't load

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I'm trying to set-up a github page with a name scheme of 'orgname.github.io'. In my case, I named my repository with "natoursqm.github.io" but I still get this '404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here." error and I don't know how will I fix this problem, I've been quite searching for answers here but most of them used a 'username.github.io' name scheme.

Comment: You may have to wait for a period of time. In my experience, the page wasn't always up in a instant.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the repo?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too but I've been quite figuring out this problem for 2 days now. It's https://github.com/quizonmarielle/natoursqm.github.io

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page will have to be the name of your GitHub username.

So in your current case, you would need to have a repo like this:

> quizonmarielle.github.io

Otherwise you'll have to create a new GitHub account with the username "natoursqm" to create a GitHub page called

> natoursqm.github.io

Also wanted to note that the GitHub page HAS to be in this format

> *your_username*.github.io

it cannot have anything extra with the username

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my github portfolio. 
https://sujithnath.github.io/sujithnath/

the URL should end with your repo name. here it is nothing but **sujithnath**

You have to configure from you repo settings.

You can read more @ https://pages.github.com/

Comment: Yes, but I was kinda trying to use an orgname name scheme instead of my username.